# How to use mathematics formula to generate DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I am calculating a housing loan table.

Basically I had variables like:

```
total_loan_amount = 1000000
downpayment = 100000
period_payment = 420
interest_rate = 0.05
```

I want to generate a dataframe like this and export it to excel:

| Years | Principal | Interest | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5711.68 | 19014.59 | 444288.32 |
| 2 | 11670.90 | 37781.66 | 438329.10 |
| 3 | 17888.37 | 56290.46 | 432111.63 |

Also, I will need to draw a chart by Python either by seaborn or matplotlib.

How do I do it? Is it must be generate each row and concat or any simple way to do it?

Comment: It depends on how you are getting the data.

Comment: What's the underlying formula for the values?

Comment: So step one it sounds like, with the given variables, you want to make a dataframe which represents something similar to what you have.   Note, you are using period Payment which is generally monthly, and your sample you are doing annual.   Next you just want to take said dataframe and render it.  BUT what are you attempting to render?  Are you trying to just do a Burndown of Balanace over time, or are you trying to add more, like a burndown of Interest as well

Comment: The TLDR of my longer message:  We need to have a precise example of what your data frame would look like which is why i note a possible miscommunication between variable name and annual string..... and also what you explicitly want visualized..

Answer (score 0):

you can use "apply" to apply functions and make new columns:

```
def add_values(a,b):
    return a+b

df["new_colum"]=df[lambda x: add_function(x.a,x.b), axis=1]
```

so you basically put all your math into functions and call them to create new columns.